# Can I repair a cake tin which has started to leak?

Tags: equipment, cake

I have a cake tin (the sprung false bottom type) which, although the bottom seems to fit quite well, has started to leak when I pour cake mixture into it.

Is there anything I can do to rescue the tin and stop it from leaking, or should I just bin it and get a new one?

Comment: Wait ... you had a springform pan that when new, *didn't* leak?  I always use mine on top of a sheet pan to catch drips.  (the sheet pan's on the lower oven rack, so it doesn't touch the pan and conduct heat)

Comment: Seriously. I didn't know that springform pans were supposed to be water-tight. I have to cradle my cheesecake pans in foil when I bake them in a water bath. Where do you buy your springforms? I'll have to start shopping there.

Comment: it always leaked a little, a few drops, but recently its started leaking a lot more, like 1/4 of my cheesecake mixture came out last time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the bottom in tin foil before squeezing it into the sides with the clasp.

Comment: good thinking batman!

Comment: tried this with a cake today and not a drop was spilt. Thanks.

Comment: exxxxcellent :)